# Dynamically injecting directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have 22 different types of ways I need to show a certain type of model. Instead of making my html have a crazy tons of if statements, and my scope, I want to create a directive for each type. I'm getting the directive from a map, based on what type it is. The function is as follows.

```
$scope.getDirective = function (item) {
    var templateDirective = getDirective(item.type);
    var dir = '<' +  templateDirective + ' listId="' + $stateParams.listId + ' item="item">'
    return dir
  }
```

the getDirective is the map I'm using. It works just fine.

The template looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in templates | orderBy: sortOrder">
  <div ng-bind-html="getDirective(item)"></div>      
</div>
```

The first issue I'm having is that when cat the string together the string looks like this

```
"<temp-ratings listId="1" item="item">"
```

The map factory I'm using.

```
.factory('getDirective', [function () {
    var templates = {
      0: "temp-check",
      1: "temp-title",
      2: "temp-ratings",
      3: "temp-ratings1_10",
      4: "temp-short",
      5: "temp-long",
      6: "temp-log",
      8: "temp-yes-no",
      9: "temp-signature",
      10: "temp-text",
      11: "temp-multiple",
      12: "temp-employee",
      13: "temp-form",
      14: "temp-calculated",
      15: "temp-date",
      16: "temp-time",
      17: "temp-date_time",
      20: "temp-qr",
      21: "temp-barcode",
      22: "temp-photo",
      23: "temp-video"
    }

    return function (tempType) {
      return templates[tempType]
    }
  }])
```

The other issue is when I inspect element. It's not even trying to inject that into the html. Does any one see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: is `getDirective` function being called from angular at all? I am suspecting your code is not working because ng-repeat creates a new scope which does not have getDirective function in it. Have to test though

Comment: Nope it's most certainly being called. A console.log and break statements show this.

Comment: Why not create a single directive that then generates the necessary html based off atrributes/data set on it? This would then keep all of your logic for the directives contained in the directive and not in the scope of a controller - which in itself breaks the methodology put in place with angular

Comment: Also where is the getDirective method that you're calling inside your $scope.getDirective?

Comment: @Darren I literally have 22 different ways to display a single model. I really do not want to include the logic into a single directive... so many if statements... ewww. I could just do ng-switch to find the right directive. But I would rather use map to the logic.

Comment: Yet you want to include the logic in a controller?

Comment: I guess without seeing exactly the sort of thing you're trying to render it's a little hard to direct. Might it be something you can do with css classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom directive to dynamically compile other directives like this:

```
.directive('tempDynamic', function ($compile, getDirective) {
  return {
    scope: {
      item: '=tempDynamic'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var templateDirective = getDirective(scope.item.type);
      var html = '<' +  templateDirective + ' item="item">';
      var childElement = $compile(html)(scope);
      element.append(childElement);
    }
  }
});
```

And use it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in templates" temp-dynamic="item"></div>
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/r5GNjklVpdbn2ADs7oSf?p=preview

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok that completely works, and it's elegant. However, I'm still completely confused as to why my way of doing it was not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Angular directives need to be compiled in order to make it works. Normally, if you have an `ng-app` in your page, angularjs will automatically compile all the elements under it when DOM loaded. After that, if you would like to dynamically add other directives you have to compile it either with `$compile` yourself, or by another machanism.